# Retained Earnings strange formula

Tags: accounting

Here is a **retained earnings** formula:

**RE = BRE + Net Income (or Loss) − D**

where **D** - dividends, **BRE** - beginning retained earnings.

Why we don't account for other things? I mean, during the reporting period the company will definetely spend its **BRE** somewhere like new assets / research and development. It seems like **BRE** will stay constant, when in reality it will decrease, but we don't account for it for some reason.

Comment: Are you sure that the things you mention are not contained in "Net income or loss"?

Comment: *Here is a retained earnings formula*... did you make up this formula? Or did you get from from somewhere (e.g. Wikipedia, textbook, etc.)? If you have an external source, does it not sufficiently explain its reasoning?

Answer (score 3):

> the company will definitely spend its BRE somewhere like new assets / research and development.

Yes - and those are accounted for elsewhere. If they spend it on assets, then they are just trading one asset for another - it has no effect on equity. If they spend it on R&D then it will be counted as an expense (possibly an asset but that's not relevant) and will reduce net income. If they pay down debt, it will reduce assets and debt, leaving equity untouched.

Dividends (and stock buybacks) are different - they are *cash out the door*. They are a way to give equity directly to the shareholders. (The earnings are no longer "retained").